# Pass variable to template on redirect - Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I try to pass a variable to template class, on a redirect, but if i try to access this variable on template, i give this error:

```
[2013-08-07 22:24:47] log.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: message' in
```

This is the actual code:

```
try {
    $loginResult = Sentry::authenticate($datas, (Input::get('remember') ? true : false));

    if($loginResult) {
        return Redirect::to('home')->with('message', array('successMessage' =>Lang::get('account.login.success'), ));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    Log::getMonolog()->warning($e->getMessage());
}
```

And this is the template part:

```
@if( $message->successMessage )
    {{ $message->successMessage }}
@endif
```

What i do wrong? Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Laravel Documentation, http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses
most probably, The 'message' is going to be an array which is actually Flash Data. So, in the view can you try :

```
<?php

$array = Session::get('message');
echo $array['successMessage'];

?>
```

And let me know if it works?

Comment: It's not works sorry. View the error message on first line, it says:
`Undefined variable: message`, but if the $message variable is an object or an array, give the following errors: 
-Try to access undefined property (Object)
-Undefined array key (Array)

Comment: Please look at the edited answer and let me know if that works!

Comment: Oh, thats going to works... I understood, if I use a View object with() function, is pass tha variable directly (On run, on request), but on redirect is not able to pass the variable directly to a new instance of th appliaction, it's write to a fast-term session to access. Thanks. ;)

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use `return Redirect::to('home')->withErrors('message',$message);`.  This way, the error message will always be made available and you don't have to include logic in your view to make sure it exists before trying to display it.